# using export option while Moving from one directory to another in Linux

Tags: linux

I am very new to Linux OS , so please excuse if my questions are dumb.

To move from one directory to another directory in Linux .
is there any difference between these two commands

```
cd /home/kiran/files
```

And

```
cd /export/home/kiran/files
```

I mean to ask whether export plays any role during moving from one directory to another directory ??

Comment: you are using absolute paths so I guess /export is something local to your system. Not something that is generally available on a Linux-system. Makes this question a bit hard to answer...

Comment: Can you post in the result of this command: ls -l /export

Comment: The name `/export` suggests that home directories are network-mounted to multiple servers. The normal location is `/home` and you should probably ignore the fact that (I presume) it is also locally visible as `/export/home`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/export isn't a standard unix directory, but if the content is the same, one (I'd guess the /export/home) is mounted at the other (/home); it's less likely but possible that there's a symbolic link (symlink) somewhere instead.

Regardless, if two directories are in fact the same, the only effective difference you'll see is if you use `..`:

```
/home/kiran $ ls
[personal files]
/home/kiran $ cd ../..
/ $ ls
bin boot etc export home [...]
/ $ cd /export/home/kiran
/export/home/kiran $ ls 
[personal files]
/export/home/kiran $ cd ../..
/export $ ls
home [other export files]
```

And those are decidedly different directories you've arrived at via the same command.

I believe that applies to symlinks too; if you've arrived via `/home/kiran`, a symlink to `../../tmp`, for example, will give you the contents of `/tmp`, but if you're there through `/export/home/kiran`, the same symlink will point you to `/export/tmp`, which may not, and probably does not, exist.

```
/home/kiran $ ln -s ../../tmp tmp
/home/kiran $ ls -l 
lrwxrwxrwx ? kiran kiran ? [timestamp] tmp -> ../../tmp
/home/kiran $ ls tmp
[temp files]
/home/kiran $ cd /export/home/kiran
/export/home/kiran $ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx ? kiran kiran ? [timestamp] tmp -> ../../tmp
/export/home/kiran $ ls tmp
tmp
```

If your `ls` is aliased to use color (or if you use `--color=yes` and your terminal supports it), you'll see teal on the /home line and red on the /export lines.  The teal is a valid symlink and red indicates a broken symlink.  (If you see green background, that's a sticky directory - anyone can make a file/directory in there but only its owner (or root of course) can delete it.)